# Create an expanding line from a point in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

im trying to create a personality picker as seen in the image below. The intended use of it is that depending on the score of each personality from 0 to 5 a black line will be drawn and expand to each of the five circles to indicate the score.

[image: Personality Picker]

Here is my code so far to create this, I have gotten the circles in line and I am currently creating the black lines however I am unable to do them dynamically and I am having to plot each point specifically which may be a problem for different screensizes. I am hoping there is a better way than what I am doing right now as it is a tonne of nested Views forming shapes. Any help would be great on how to make this simpiler / more dynamic!
Thanks :)

```
return (
        <View style={{margin: 32}}>
            <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular', fontSize: 36}}>Plot your{"\n"}personality</Text>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <Text style={{
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular',
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: '#878787',
                    paddingTop: 4,
                    alignSelf: 'flex-end'
                }}>Use this to match with similar people?</Text>
                <Switch
                    trackColor={{false: "#878787", true: "#5BF675"}}
                    thumbColor="#f4f3f4"
                    ios_backgroundColor="#878787"
                    onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                    value={isEnabled}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 32}}>
                <View style={{
                    borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    height: 275,
                    width: 275,
                    borderRadius: 275 / 2,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <View style={{
                        borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        height: 225,
                        width: 225,
                        borderRadius: 225 / 2,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}>
                        <View style={{
                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            height: 175,
                            width: 175,
                            borderRadius: 175 / 2,
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            <View style={{
                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                height: 125,
                                width: 125,
                                borderRadius: 125 / 2,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center'
                            }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    height: 75,
                                    width: 75,
                                    borderRadius: 75 / 2,
                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                    justifyContent: 'center'
                                }}>
                                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                                borderWidth: 1,
                                                width: 275,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                                borderWidth: 1,
                                                width: 275,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                                borderWidth: 1,
                                                width: 275,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                                borderWidth: 1,
                                                width: 275,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: 90.5,
                                                    bottom: -3,
                                                    left: 0,
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '0deg'}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: 137.5,
                                                    bottom: -52,
                                                    right: -116,
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: 137.5,
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    bottom: -72,
                                                    left: -70,
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: 137.5,
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}, {translateX: 68}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: 137.5,
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}, {scaleX: 0}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: 137.5,
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '225deg'}, {translateX: 68}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: 137.5,
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '270deg'}, {translateX: 68}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                            <View
                                                style={{
                                                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                                    width: (137.5),
                                                    alignItems: 'center',
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    transform: [{ rotate: '315deg'}, {translateX: 68}],
                                                    position: 'absolute',
                                                }}
                                            />
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is a cleaner solution for this (maybe I will add one later), but for now, lets try and make your code work.
You can have dynamic line size by passing the width to each View component with a math formula. meaning, think of a way to represent the size of each line. for example:
0: 0px,
1: 50px,
2: 100px
and so on... (the 50px should be the radius divided by 5)

Now, for each View tag, you can just set the width by multiplying 50px with the value of the size of it(0-5: 0-250px).
This should do the trick.

(I assume you have a state or a way to keep the values of each label, and by that you multiply this value with 50px for each line)

Hey, sorry for taking so long I wasn't available so much. anyway, I wrote a small piece of code that does the behavior you want. the design isn't amazing but it does the trick. I used [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) just for fun, you can run it easily by installing styled-component or just converting it to regular form:

App.js

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Line from './components/line';

function App() {

  const [values, setValues] = useState(config);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Circle>
        <Center/>
        <Lines>{values.map((value) => <Line {...value} />)}</Lines></Circle>
      <Menu>
        {values.map((line, index) => 
          <SizeButtons>
            <Button onClick={() => {
                const copyValues = [...values];
                copyValues[index].value = line.value - 1 > 0 ? line.value - 1 : 0;
                setValues(copyValues);
              }}>-</Button>
              <Button onClick={() => {
                const copyValues = [...values];
                copyValues[index].value = line.value + 1 < 5 ? line.value + 1 : 5;
                setValues(copyValues);
              }}>+</Button>
          </SizeButtons>
        )}
      </Menu>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;

const Container = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
`;

const Circle = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
`;

const Center = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 116px;
  left: 116px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
`;

const Lines = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 125px;
  left: 125px;
`;

const SizeButtons = styled.div``;

const Menu = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
`;

const Button = styled.button``;

const config = [
  { value: 1, degree: 0 },
  { value: 1, degree: 45, },
  { value: 1, degree: 90, left: '2px' },
  { value: 1, degree: 135, top: '2px', left: '1px' },
  { value: 1, degree: 181, top: '2px' },
  { value: 1, degree: 225, top: '0px' },
  { value: 1, degree: 270, top: '0px' },
  { value: 1, degree: 315, top: '0px' },
]
```

line.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Line = (props) => {
    return (
        <Container {...props}/>
    );
};

export default Line;

const Container = styled.div`
    width: ${props => props.value * 25 }px;    
    background: black;
    height: 2px;
    transform: rotate(${props => props.degree}deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: absolute;
    top: ${props => props.top};
    left: ${props => props.left}
`;
```

let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Hi, I found a solution on my own but it is not the neatest in the slightest nor am I happy with it. Ill add an answer to the question and if possible id love to see how you do it that would help as I worry it will not be responsive for different screens

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer, although I am not 100% satisfied and believe it may fall over when screens resize.

```
    import React from 'react';
import {View} from "react-native";

interface PersonalityPlotterDialProps {
    value: number
}

function PersonalityPlotterDial(props: PersonalityPlotterDialProps) {
    const {value} = props;

    const widthCalculator = (value: number) => {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                return 37.5;
            case 2:
                return 62.5;
            case 3:
                return 87.5;
            case 4:
                return 112.5;
            case 5:
                return 137.5;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    };

    const translateCalculator = (value: number) => {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                return 1.05;
            case 2:
                return 1.75;
            case 3:
                return 2.5;
            case 4:
                return 3.2;
            case 5:
                return 3.95;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    const displayCalculator = () => {
        if (widthCalculator(value) === 0) {
            return 'none'
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 32, marginBottom: 64}}>
            <View style={{
                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                borderWidth: 1,
                height: 275,
                width: 275,
                borderRadius: 275 / 2,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    height: 225,
                    width: 225,
                    borderRadius: 225 / 2,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <View style={{
                        borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        height: 175,
                        width: 175,
                        borderRadius: 175 / 2,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}>
                        <View style={{
                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            height: 125,
                            width: 125,
                            borderRadius: 125 / 2,
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            <View style={{
                                borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                height: 75,
                                width: 75,
                                borderRadius: 75 / 2,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                position: 'relative'
                            }}>
                                <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View
                                        style={{
                                            borderColor: '#DBDBDB',
                                            borderWidth: 1,
                                            width: 275,
                                            alignItems: 'center',
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                            transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
                                            position: 'absolute',
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                bottom: -3,
                                                left: 0,
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '0deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '135deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                bottom: -3,
                                                right: 0,
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '225deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '270deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                        <View
                                            style={{
                                                backgroundColor: '#000',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                width: widthCalculator(value),
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                                transform: [{ rotate: '315deg'}, {translateX: (translateCalculator(value)) * 17.5}],
                                                position: 'absolute',
                                                display: displayCalculator(),
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default PersonalityPlotterDial;
```